# How do I connect my Html page with my CSS stylesheet?

Tags: html, css

I have something like this in the body of my Html page.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/untitled2.css">
```

I'm pretty sure this correct, but it's not working. What is wrong here?

Comment: Please add your code.

Answer (score 1):

You add your style sheets to the header such as

```
<head>
     <!-- everything else -->
     <link href="css/main.css"type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

If you want to add it to the `body` you can style each element by using the `style` attribute such as ...

```
<body style="color:black;"></body>
```

or on each element itself

Comment: it's not `//everything else` but `<!-- everything else -->`. ;)

Comment: Though be advised that inline styles are generally frowned upon.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is right inside the page you are looking at, try to figure out yourself as much as possible before asking the question here.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=7bbb71ecd5eb">
```

( from StackOverflow's page source )